# Ist diese Verwendung von 'Eskapade' im Sinne eines belastenden Verhaltens korrekt?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

Wenn der Wecker morgens klingelt, drücke ich gern häufig auf die "Snooze"-Taste, sodass das wiederholte Klingeln des Weckers für jeden, der einen leichteren Schlaf hat, schwer zu ertragen ist.

Ich könnte also sagen:

> Meine morgendlichen Wecker-**Eskapaden** sind wirklich eine Zumutung für meinen Zimmergenossen.

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob der Begriff *Eskapade* hier richtig genutzt wird.

Der Duden listet als mögliche Bedeutungen auch "eigenwillige Handlung", was meiner angestrebten Verwendung des Wortes zumindest recht nahe kommt.

Ist der Begriff hier richtig genutzt? Falls nein, was wäre eine (eloquente) Entsprechung, um das belastende Verhalten besser auszudrücken?

Comment: Ich denke, ohne das genauer belegen zu können, dass _Eskapaden_ heute im Begriff ist in seiner Bedeutung zu verflachen und eine Bedeutung im Sinne von _Begebenheit_ bekommt oder bekommen hat. Das steht so weder im duden, noch dwds noch wiktionary, aber meine Alltagsbeobachtung scheint mir das zu belegen.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach gefühlsmäßig würde ich dir Recht geben, aber was leitest du aus dieser Beobachtung im Hinblick auf meine Frage ab?

Comment: Naja, ich würde sagen, dass deine Verwendung dieser Entwicklung entspricht. Aber natürlich ist wichtig, was du genau ausdrücken willst. Wenn du schon in dem Wort (nicht nur im Satz) eine besondere soziale Devianz / Problematik deines Wecker-Verhaltens ausdrücken willst, ist vielleicht auch _Marotte_ oder _Macke_ ganz passend, aber _Eskapade_ in der ersten Bedeutung trifft es eigentlich auch ganz gut.

Comment: Die Eskapade als "eigenwillige Handlung" hat schon eine gewisse Bedeutung. Zur Beantwortung der Frage wäre es wichtig zu wissen, um was für "eigenwillige Handlungen" mit dem Wecker denn geht. Je nach dem wäre vielleicht tatsächlich ein anderer Begriff passender.

Comment: Ich finde, man kann die Frage nicht beantworten, ohne zu wissen, was konkret diese morgendlichen "Wecker-Eskapaden" sind. Was tut die Person? Lässt sie den Wecker zu lange klingeln? Bekommt sie Wutanfälle und wirft den Wecker aus dem Fenster? Stellt sie den Wecker aus, um dem drohenden Aufstehen zu entfliehen?

Comment: Ich sehe an diesem Wecker absolut nichts Unmoralisches.
Die Frage ist was der Wecker sonst noch für Capriolen und Seitensprünge macht. Wenn er natürlich jeden Tat eine halbe Stunde vorgeht, sollte man sich besser einen neuen kaufen.

Comment: DR WECKER SONGTEXT
leider geit ir nacht my wecker
immer füf minute vor
lütet mir drum jede morge
füf minute z'früech is ohr
aber wen i ne am abe
füf minute hinder tät
wär i drum de bim i-ds-bett-ga
wider füf minute z'spät
syg's am abe, syg's am morge
s'nimmt mehr füf minute pfuus
füf minute sy nid vil,
doch mit der zyt macht's öppis us
i zwölf tag isch das e stund
und i drei monet scho ne nacht
won i wäg däm blöde wecker
schliesslech schlaflos hät verbracht
i ha sorge wäg myr gsundheit
uswäglos isch d'situation
zletscht han ig dr wecker furtggäh
sider weckt my ds telefon

Comment: Danke für die Hinweise zum Verbessern der Frage. Habe entsprechende inhaltliche Ergänzungen hinzugefügt.

Comment: Um bei französischen Periphrasen zu bleiben, "Allüren" (auffallendes Benehmen oder Umgansgformen) wäre wohl besser (gewesen :-))  als "Eskapaden" (Entwischen, Seietnsprünge, Ausweichen). (Quelle: dwds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meines Wissens ist die Verwendung in dem Satz korrekt. Speziell die Bezeichnung "eigenwillige Handlung" scheint mir in dem Zusammenhang passend, jedoch nicht vollständig. Ich denke einige zusätzliche Adjektive würden es besser beschreiben:
Eigenartig, ungewöhnlich, störend, unpassend, unerwartet.

Wenn man den Worthersprung verfolgt, kommt es ja vom Dressurreiten, wo es eine unerwartete und unpassende Handlung des Pferdes beschreibt, eine Art Flucht -> Eskapade (vgl. z.B. Eskapismus, escape(englisch), échapper(französisch)). Diese für den Reiter willkürliche Handlung wurde im Laufe der Zeit auf Menschen übertragen und beschreibt eigenwillige, unerwartete und oft unangenehme Handlungen.

Answer (score 1):

Aber sicher ist das richtig. Wenn hier jemand sagen würde, das sei falsch, und wäre es Herr Duden höchst persönlich, würde das ja den Stillstand der Weiterentwicklung unserer Sprache bedeuten.

Diese Formulierung ist sehr lustig! Man sieht gerade förmlich vor dem geistigen Auge den Wecker, wie er  auf dem Nachttischlein eigenwillig herumgaloppiert.

Es spielt übrigens keine Rolle, ob damit die Eskapaden des Weckers gemeint sind oder deine nächtlichen, oder auch nur, dass du dich selber vergaloppiert hast und den Wecker falsch gestellt hast.

Comment: Ich sehe das ähnlich. Eine Eskapade ist ja eigentlich ein falscher Sprung (eines Pferdes) zur Seite. Als Metapher wurde der Seitensprung daraus. Selbst wenn die Eskapade beim Wecker metaphorisch gemeint wäre, müsste man sich bei einer _Wecker-Eskapade_ einen springenden Wecker vorstellen, zum Beispiel physisch, als hüpfender Wecker, oder so, dass die Uhrzeit sich verstellt.

Answer (score 1):

Eine *Eskapade* ist eine eigenwillige, unwillkürliche und unerwartete Handlung - wenn du also den Wecker morgens durch das geschlossene Fenster auf die Strasse wirfst, ihn im Waschbecken versenkst oder anzündest (oder sogar eine Woche mit ihm nach Paris durchbrennst) - wäre das schon den Begriff "Eskapade" wert.

Wenn du ihn nur eine halbe Stunde lang klingeln lässt, dann eher nicht. Das machen ja alle.

Das Letztere ist dann eher *ein Drama* (vor allem für die, die eigentlich ausschlafen wollten)

Answer (score 0):

*Eskapaden* könnte gut mit *Ausflüchte* gleichgesetzt werden. Insofern deine Wecker-Eskapaden wie meine händeringend nach Entschuldigungen suchen um der kalten realität zu entfliehen, würde das Wort sogar vortrefflich passen.

**Edit** nach der Frage-Ergänzung:

Es würde sicherlich einen Ausdruck geben, der dasselbe auch ohne jenen Zusatz ausdrückt.

Ein Zimmernachbar, wenn der Wecker zur Belastung wird,  dächtee wohl eher an

> **Tortur**

Etwas sachlicher ginge es vielleicht auch. Dem Pferdesport-Ursprung von *Eskapade* wegen kommt *Scheu* in den Sinn. Als synonym zu Eskapade im umganssprachlichen Sinn, weniger sachlich etwa auch *Sperenzchen* (auch *Sperenzien*) oder *Allüren*. Etwas hin und her übersetzt von *tantrum* zu *Anfall* (was ja beides eher entgegengesetzt zu Schlaf ist, wogegen *spastics* gewissermaßen passend wäre, aber zu abfällig) zu *demeanor* bzw. *fuss*, findet sich unter [fuss](https://www.dict.cc/?s=fuss) eine lange Liste, mit bspw. **Gewese** (was aber selten jemandem den Schlaf raubt) und *Theater* (was nah an @trofo's *Drama wäre). Auch sehr schön *Fisimatenten*.

*Eskapade* passt, wie bereits mehrfach gesagt wurde, relativ gut.

Comment: Die einzige Verbindung zu *Ausflucht*, die ich erkennen kann, ist das ähliche englische *escape*, danach war aber nicht gefragt.

Comment: @guidot die Verbindung ist wohl nicht rein zufällig. [https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ausflucht) - *prevarication* - 1. *(now rare) Deviation from what is right or correct; transgression, perversion.* 2. *Evasion of the truth; deceit, evasiveness* 3. ...  Man könnte vielleicht auch von *Entgleisung* sprechen, danach war aber nicht gefragt.

Comment: @guidot entschuldig mal, hast du grad meinen zweiten Kommentar über *capio* "capture, grab*, *was nimmst du dir heraus?* gelöscht?